# How and where to set "commandLineArgs": "--pathbase=/myapp" in Hosted Blazor App

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor

When deployed .net core hosted Blazor app is served from myserver.com/myapp.

I've set `<base href="/myapp/" />` in index.html and it works when published.

To avoid changing it all the time manually I tried to follow [official documentation on Path Base](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/aspnet/core/blazor/host-and-deploy/webassembly?view=aspnetcore-3.1#path-base) and to add:

1. `"commandLineArgs": "--pathbase=/myapp"` or
2. `"commandLineArgs": "--pathbase=/"` even
3. `"commandLineArgs": "--pathbase="`

in `launchSettings.json`.

I've tried putting it in all configuration profiles but for some reason it does not work when debugging. It can't find resources.

I've also tried running from console: `dotnet run --pathbase=/myapp` but no luck.

**EDIT**: `--pathbase=/myapp` works for stand alone Blazor apps, but not for ASP.NET Core hosted one. At least not out of the box.

Is there a way to pass this config from "Server" to "Client" or to tell to the "Client" to use it in debug mode?

Comment: I am having the same issue :( I have tried passing it to the aspnetcore project that is hosting the blazor client but it simply says: 
Unknown option: --pathbase=/Prod

Comment: Why are you setting the path manually? Why can't you use [the `ContentRoot` as set in the `HostEnvironment` 'automatically'](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/generic-host?view=aspnetcore-5.0#contentroot)

Comment: I'm having a similar issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71113666/how-to-host-blazor-webassembly-app-with-different-base-path

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and my solution was to set the following

In index.html

```
<base href="/myapp/" />
```

In launchSettings.json

```
"commandLineArgs": "--pathbase=/myapp",
"launchUrl": "myapp",
```

Comment: Can you provide a complete 'launchsettings.json'.  The one I have (that VS uses) has multiple sections.  Which one will IIS use?